# In maven, what is the difference between main/resources and main/config?

Tags: maven-2

I want to put a configuration file in my Maven project. Looking at [the standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), there are two places that seem sensible, "`src/main/resources`" and "`src/main/config`". Could someone explain the difference between these, and explain when you would put something in `config` and when in `resources`?

In this case, the file I'm looking at is `ehcache.xml`, but my question isn't ehcache specific, I'm curious for `log4j.properties` etc.

A bit of googling discovered [this person had the same question](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Porpuse-of-src-main-config-td124167.html), but the answers seemed contradictory, and not very authorative.

Comment: I think I found a use case for the main/config directory. I have a couple of configuration files that are optional to use and are not useful in the classpath. Example configuration files for the app and the container it is deployed on. I can't find anywhere any other place for them.

Comment: This might be a good place for eclipse plug-in config files (findbugs, checkstyle, etc.) I wouldn't want those bundled in the archive file.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The email exchange at http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg90985.html
says:

"*This is all theory... Perhaps while writing the docs, someone involved with Maven development thought it might be useful to have a src/main/config directory and so it was included in docs, but since it was never implemented in the code, it is not being used today.*"

and

"*The directory* [src/main/config] *doesn't show up on the classpath so the application or test classes
can't read anything in it.*"

So just use `src/main/resources`.

Note: I don't know if this is true (I'm the question asker), but that would explain why so many people on the web recommend `src/main/resources` for log4j.properties. If people agree this is the right answer could you let me know (comment or vote) I put it here to save other people the typing.

Comment: This is correct, just use `src/xxx/resources` for all non sources files you want to get on the classpath. Sure, you can decide to add other directories but you'll need to add specific configuration to the POM.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I was looking at the documentation and the [standard directory layout section](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) makes no mention of this :(

Comment: I use src/main/config to hold configuration items that I don't want packaged into the target, like JBoss configuration scripts.

Answer (score 9):

`scr/main/resources` is a place where you put your images, sounds, templates, language bundles, textual and binary files used by the source code. All config files like excache.xml, log4j.properties, logback.xml and others go to `src/main/config`.

Add to your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>.</targetPath>
            <directory>src/main/config</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: this seems sensible to me, but do you have a reference? There are various emails, eg http://markmail.org/message/lve4d2qzba2lritd saying resources is the standard placement for log4j.properties

Comment: Can't find any. It's just a common sense. Wherever you put it just make sure it's on a classpath so it will be picked up by log4j library.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a standard way to add this directory to the classpath under maven? (I'm a new maven user)

Comment: @Nick you can follow your own rule but src/xxx/resources is indeed the standard placement for configuration files in practice.

Comment: Anytime you need to explicitly supply a directory to a Maven config you're doing something non-standard. I personally put files like log4j.properties in src/main/resources and it "just works".

Comment: I agree with this solution. Things you put in `src/main/resources` by default become part of your jar file. If you want your config files to live *outside* of your jars then I believe it makes more sense to use `src/main/config`. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 7):

The inclusion of `src/main/config` in [Maven's standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) has been removed due in part to the confusion caused between `src/main/config` and `src/main/resources`.  This very stackoverflow question is actually referenced in the [JIRA ticket for the removal of `src/main/config` from Maven's standard](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNGSITE-253).

Short answer: Use `src/main/resources` not `src/main/config`.  It's the (new) Maven way.

Answer (score 0):

Use case is pretty straightforward if you ask me. (It seems src/main/config has since been removed standard directory layout)

- /src/main/resources go on into jar and thus on classpath
- /src/main/config is intended for assembly plugin where you might construct a 
  zip file:

  ```
  hello-world.zip
   lib/
    <dependencies>
   bin/
    run.bat
    run.sh
   config/
    config.properies
  ```