# Why isn't hibernate.cfg.xml in src/main/config by default?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I was just reading the Maven Standard Directory Layout (because that's what I do on Friday nights) and it seems that config files should be in `src/main/config`. But Hibernate, by default, looks in `src/main/resource` for hibernate.cfg.xml. Why is this?

For reference: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Note that Hibernate doesn't "look" in any of those directories, it's Maven that enforces such directory layout. In fact, Hibernate simply looks at the root of the classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that `resources` is runtime resources for the application. `config` is for maven related configuration e.g. for plugins.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers in this thread, especially the answer that links to a mailing list discussion:

[In maven, what is the difference between main/resources and main/config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182794/in-maven-what-is-the-difference-between-main-resources-and-main-config)

Comment: That thread is good -- however, it looks like there is disagreement over when to use resources vs. config.