# Can't add dynamic property to Maven's resource located at build path

Tags: maven, maven-3, war, maven-archetype

I'm trying to setup properties in my `config.ini` which located in `src/main/config` by using `pom.xml` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11740748/947111), but it doesn't work.

I've placed to `src/main/config` file `config.ini` where the following line is present: `runtime_mode=${runtime.mode}` when I try to access at runtime `runtime_mode` key I get string `${runtime.mode}` instead of **DEBUG** or **PRODUCTION** as defined in `pom.xml`. When I use `${runtime.mode}` in `*.html` file it's being replaced by appropriate value as expected.

So, it doesn't work only when resource located at build path.

I suspect that I define resource in a wrong way, but can't realize what's wrong.

This is build part of my `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <runtime.mode>DEBUG</runtime.mode>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/config</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
         </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                          <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                          <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                          <filtering>true</filtering>
                          <includes>
                              <include>bower.json</include>
                              <include>index.html</include>
                          </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My app is a `war` project created by using the following archetype:

```
<archetype>
      <groupId>com.ibm.tools.archetype</groupId>
      <artifactId>webapp-jee7-liberty</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <description>JEE7 web application targeting WebSphere Liberty archetype</description>
</archetype>
```

**UPDATE**:
Moved my `config.ini` to `src\main\resources` and changed my `<resource>` tag as following:

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>config.ini</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

But now I can't read any resource located in `src/main/resources` from code, for example I put there `sql.xml` where all my sql queries.

Trying read by following code:

```
private static Properties readProperties(String xmlFileName) throws Exception {
         Properties properties = new Properties();
         InputStream is = SQLProvider.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xmlFileName);
         properties.loadFromXML(is);
         return properties;
    }
```

But it throws an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.Properties.loadFromXML(Properties.java:881) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at ***.SQLProvider.readProperties(SQLProvider.java:26) ~[classes/:?]
```

Comment: Does your archetype have an archetype.xml or an archetype-metadata.xml in the META-INF directory?

Comment: First: put `config.ini` in `src/main/resources` instead. That folder is specifically for that kind of files. Second: the replacement happens because of the `<filtering>true</filtering>` element in the `pom.xml` file, but you have not included `config.ini` in the filtering. That is why the replacement only happens in the `index.html` file.

Comment: @Ahatius, no, it hasn't

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors, do you mean to add `<includes>config.ini</includes>` at resource tag? Regarding config vs resources I've found interesting answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4183095/947111 will try to implement it right now

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors, tried to make a change as you suggested but it doesn't work, I've updated my question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of luck there because I am entirely unfamiliar with that archetype.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [maven-replacer-plugin](http://www.developerfusion.com/project/19900/mavenreplacerplugin/)  you can replace any token defined in external file.

Example

```
      <properties>
         <runtime.mode>DEBUG</runtime.mode>
      </properties>

     <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <ignoreMissingFile>false</ignoreMissingFile>
                <file>path to file/config.ini</file>
                <regex>false</regex>
                <replacements>
                    <replacement>
                        <token>$runtime.mode$</token>
                        <value>${runtime.mode}</value>
                    </replacement>
                </replacements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```